# Beaker fails to find Python

Tags: python, jupyter, beaker

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't found a response that helps me and apparently I don't have enough points to add a comment, so I'm going to post this as a new question.

I installed beaker and followed the instructions to connect it with my previous python installations with no luck. I have even reinstalled anaconda and installed in the same directory as the instructions, and still it does not work.

When I ask where my python is i get:

```
which python
/anaconda3/bin/ipython

which python3
/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

So, my beaker.pref.json file is:

```
 {
   "pref-format" : "1",
   "allow-anonymous-usage-tracking" : true,
  "languages" : {
"IPython" : {
  "path" : "Users/eudald/anaconda3/bin/"
},
"Python3" : {
  "path" : "/Users/eudald/anaconda3/bin"
}
 },
     "advanced-mode" : false,
"edit-mode" : "default"
}
```

Still, I get this message:

Language Error
Failed to start IPython.

Did you install it according to the instructions on BeakerNotebook.com?

If you already have it, then edit your preferences file to help Beaker find it on your system, and then restart Beaker and try again.

Any other languages in your notebook should still work.

Furthermore, I have had tons of problems with Jupyter notebooks and environments, having to resort to the option of --system-site-packages when creating an environment, even though I know it's not optimal.

My OS is 10.13.2 and I'm running the last versions of conda, python, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: I don't have python 2 installed, can this cause a problem?

Comment: can you explain how the other solutions you have seen didnt work?

Comment: Yes, I run this command:
`python -m ipykernel install --user
Installed kernelspec python2 in /Users/admin/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python2`

following this thread:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310553/beaker-fails-to-find-python-and-julia-installations-despite-following-installati)

Comment: Of course I have also tried the obvious: reinstall conda, python, beaker, basically anything that could be reinstalled. I have also changed the beaker pats and checked that the .bash_profile path is the correct one